# Change the default 'email' column for login, register and password reset in Laravel 7.x

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working with an existing table which I cannot change the column name for email, so I need to use the existing column name which is 'email_address' instead of the default 'email'

This is what I`ve find and implemented so far:

User.php model

```
public function getEmailAttribute()
{
    return $this->email_address;
}

public function setEmailAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['email_address'] = $value;
}

public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->email_address;
}

public function routeNotificationFor($driver, $notification = null)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method = 'routeNotificationFor'.Str::studly($driver))) {
        return $this->{$method}($notification);
    }

    switch ($driver) {
        case 'database':
            return $this->notifications();
        case 'mail':
            return $this->email_address;
    }
}

public function recentlyCreatedToken(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
{
    $record = (array) $this->getTable()->where(
        'email_address', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
    )->first();

    return $record && $this->tokenRecentlyCreated($record['created_at']);
}
```

LoginController.php

```
public function username()
{
    return 'email_address';
}
```

RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email_address' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:web_volunteers'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email_address' => $data['email_address'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}


ForgotPasswordController.php

protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['email_address' => 'required|email']);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('email_address');
}

protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email_address' => [trans($response)],
        ]);
    }

    return back()
            ->withInput($request->only('email_address'))
            ->withErrors(['email_address' => trans($response)]);
}
```

The templates input fiels are also changed to name="email_address" and until here, the Login and Register processes are working perfectly, but not the recover password process.

When trying to recover password, I get the 'undefined "email" column' error so I`ve looked closer inside the debuging error and I`ve seen that 'email' is called amd hardcoded inside the DatabaseTokenRepository.php . 
I was fine updating the controllers and the model, but not this file from the vendor files.
Just for test, I`ve changed the following methods inside DatabaseTokenRepository.php

```
protected function deleteExisting(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
{
    return $this->getTable()->where('email_address', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset())->delete();
}

protected function getPayload($email, $token)
{
    return ['email_address' => $email, 'token' => $this->hasher->make($token), 'created_at' => new 
Carbon];
}

public function exists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
{
    $record = (array) $this->getTable()->where(
        'email_address', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
    )->first();

    return $record &&
           ! $this->tokenExpired($record['created_at']) &&
             $this->hasher->check($token, $record['token']);
}

public function recentlyCreatedToken(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
{
    $record = (array) $this->getTable()->where(
        'email_address', $user->getEmailForPasswordReset()
    )->first();

    return $record && $this->tokenRecentlyCreated($record['created_at']);
}
```

Updating this methods, the password reset process works too, so everything is working, but I`m still no happy updating the vendor code. Is there an easier way to override those methods ? or any other idea to achieve this is welcome.